# How to print the index values of two identical items in a list?

Tags: python, string, list, count, indexing

list = ["car", "bus", "car", "truck", "van", "bus", "truck"]

Say I wanted all the "cars"'s to be changed to "bikes". I understand how to do it for the first "car" by indexing it etc. But how would I change all the "cars"'s to bikes simultaneously? I would like to know how to count all the instances of "car" and then index however many times "car" is in the list, but if I do this normally, then only the first instance is returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my_list = ["car", "bus", "car", "truck", "van", "bus", "truck"]
my_list[:] = ["bikes" if ele == "car" else ele for ele in my_list]

my_list
['bikes', 'bus', 'bikes', 'truck', 'van', 'bus', 'truck']
```

To get the indexes use `enumerate`:

```
indexes = [ind for ind,ele in enumerate(my_list) if ele =="car"]
```

And the car count will be the length of the indexes list:

```
car_count = len(indexes)
```

Comment: What's the advantage of using `my_list[:] = ...` over `my_list = ...`?

Comment: @RogerFan, `my_list` still points to the same object where as using `my_list = ` creates a new object

Comment: But the list comprehension is creating the new object. Why take the extra step of trying to shoehorn it into the original `my_list` object? Just move the tag over to the new list. I guess it might matter if there's a local/global variable thing going on?

Comment: Sure it is. It just doesn't get a name assigned to it. But the list is still created. You can use a generator expression instead if you don't want to create an intermediate list.

Comment: @RogerFan, why don't you check the id before and after

Comment: That doesn't mean an intermediate list isn't created. The list comprehension creates a new intermediate list, then the `my_list[:] = ...` puts that list into the existing my_list object. My point is that you could also just rename the intermediate list to `my_list` and get the same result in a lot of cases. The big exception being some kind of mutable-argument local/global variable situation, where you probably want to think carefully about which way you want to use.

Comment: I'd just like to say thanks to @PadraicCunningham as I manipulated the second part of your answer (indexes = [ind for ind,ele in enumerate(my_list) if ele =="car"]) to incorporate into my hangman game I am making. I used my question to try and help with changing multiple asterisk's into letters in my hangman game, as I would always get the first index of the word changed into a letter.

E.g. if the word was "pumpkin", then if I entered the letter "p" as a guess, the asterisks' would change to p******, but now they change to p**p*** thanks to this alteration. So thanks a lot!